# R: Finding indirect links between colleagues. Code works with string ids, but not numeric ids

Tags: r, list

I am trying the extract the set of indirect colleagues of doctors. I call colleagues doctors who work together in the same hospital. An indirect colleague is a doctor who works with the colleague of a doctor in another hospital. In the example below, doctor "a" works with doctor "b" in hospital 1, who in turn work with doctor "c" in hospital 2. Therefore "c" is an indirect colleague of "a".

The code below works well when physician id constitutes of string values (df0) or low numeric values (df1), but not when physicians id constitutes of high numeric value (df2). I would like to fix the code to work with high numeric values (while keeping the original ids of physicians).

```
df0 <- tribble(
  ~hospital, ~doctors,
  1, c("a", "b"),
  2, c("b", "c"),
  3, c("a", "d"),
) %>%
  unnest(doctors)

# Below, I replaced doctor id with numeric values
df1 <- tribble(
  ~hospital, ~doctors,
  1, c(1, 2),
  2, c(2, 3),
  3, c(1, 4),
) %>%
  unnest(doctors)

# Now I added +5 to each physician id 
df2 <- tribble(
  ~hospital, ~doctors,
  1, c(6, 7),
  2, c(7, 8),
  3, c(6, 9)
) %>%
  unnest(doctors)

df <- df2 # The code only works with df0 and df1, not with df2

colleagues <- full_join(df, df, by = c("hospital")) %>%
  rename(doctor = doctors.x, colleagues = doctors.y) %>%
  filter(doctor != colleagues) %>%
  distinct(doctor, colleagues) %>%
  chop(colleagues) %>%
  deframe()

colleagues %>%  
  enframe(name = "ego",
          value = "alter") %>%
  unnest(alter) %>%
  mutate(ego_colleagues = map(ego, ~ colleagues[[.x]]),
         alter_colleagues = map(alter, ~ colleagues[[.x]]),
         alter_colleague_only = map2(alter_colleagues, ego_colleagues, ~ .x[!(.x %in% .y)])) %>%
  unnest(alter_colleague_only) %>%
  filter(ego != alter_colleague_only) %>%
  select(ego, alter, alter_colleague_only)
```

Comment: What results do you want? There are better ways to solve the problem

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could shed me some light on how to better solve this if you have another idea. I would want the result `data.frame(ego = c(6, 7, 8, 9), alter = c(7, 6, 7, 6), alter_colleague_only = c(8, 9, 6, 7))`

Comment: When you start with `df0` what do you expect? `df0` has `hospital` and `doctors` there is nothing like `ego` in it

Comment: When I start with `df0` I would expect `data.frame(ego = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), alter = c("b", "a", "b", "a"), alter_colleague_only = c("c", "d", "a", "b"))`.

Comment: why cant b and d be related indirectly?

Comment: Also what if one person has multiple direct contacts? Do you list all or just chose 1 randomly?

Comment: Doctors b and d are indeed related indirectly and this is informed in the 2nd row in the output as variables `ego` and `alter_colleague_only`; the indirect link happens through working with doctor a in different hospitals (variable `alter`). If a person has multiple direct contacts the code will list them all (you can add "e" to hospital 3 and will see that now both d and e are indirect colleagues of b, both through doctor a). The code does the job when physician ids are string, but not when numeric. This is the main issue I would say.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `map` calls. Using `df2`, when you `map(ego, ~ colleagues[[.x]])`, `colleagues[.x]` is indexing by position, not name. When you use character names, it defaults to using character names. When you use numeric names and they're 1, 2, 3, 4 it happens to work by luck. But when you have a list of 4 and you're calling `colleagues[[6]]`, then you get the index out of bounds error. If that's not totally clear, print these:
`colleagues[[1]]` vs. `colleagues[[6]]` vs. `` colleagues$`6` `` .
A quick fix would be to wrap the first part of those map statements in as.character like this:

```
    colleagues %>%  
      enframe(name = "ego",
              value = "alter") %>%
      unnest(alter) %>%
      mutate(ego_colleagues = map(as.character(ego), ~ colleagues[[.x]]),
             alter_colleagues = map(as.character(alter), ~ colleagues[[.x]]),
             alter_colleague_only = map2(as.character(alter_colleagues), as.character(ego_colleagues), ~ .x[!(.x %in% .y)])) %>%
      unnest(alter_colleague_only) %>%
      filter(ego != alter_colleague_only) %>%
      select(ego, alter, alter_colleague_only)
```

UPDATE:
Depending on your setup, you could try using the `furrr` package with `future_map` and `future_map2`, but at least in this minimal example that was a much slower approach. I don't know if that holds true on your real data.

Here's another option. While ugly because it has a lot of intermediate objects, it may be helpful. It uses matrices and leverages the fact that you have these reciprocal relationships (if I'm interpreting correctly). I benchmarked it and it takes half as long.

```
    t1 <- colleagues %>%
      enframe(name = "ego",
              value = "alter") %>%
      unnest(alter) %>% 
      filter(!duplicated(paste0(pmax(ego, alter), pmin(ego, alter)))) %>%
      as.matrix() 
    
    t2 <- t1 %>%
      rbind(t1[1:nrow(t1),c(2,1)])
    alter_colleague_only <- t2[match(t2[,2], t2[,1]), "alter"]
    t3 <- cbind(t2, alter_colleague_only)
    t4 <- t3[which(t2[,1] != t3[,3]),]
    t5 <- t4[,c(3,2,1)]
    t6 <- rbind(t4, t5) %>%
      as_tibble() %>%
      arrange(ego)
```

Comment: Many thanks! This seems to work, the only change I would make is to remove `as.character()` from the `map2` function and then this works fine and I get the desired output which is `data.frame(ego = c(6, 7, 8, 9), alter = c(7, 6, 7, 6), alter_colleague_only = c(8, 9, 6, 7))`.

Comment: The only issue is that this is infeasible with my real data is massive (I have 150k different doctor ids and my data has millions of rows) and working with strings would make it too time demanding (maybe it would not even run). Is there a way to change the code and keep the codes as numeric? Unfortunately, `map(ego, ~ colleagues$`.x`)` does not work.